# Simple Math in Django template

Tags: python, django

I have a table setup in my templates with pagination and at the bottom left side it shows how many items are shown, like this:

[image]

Here `10` is called `count` and `19` is `total`.

If I go the next page ( as of now I have only 2 pages worth of data in my table ) it shows `Showing 9 of 19 items`.

I want to modify this slightly to show it as `Showing 1 - 10 of 19` and then `Showing 11 - 19 of 19`. It seems pretty simple algorithmically . All I have to do is initialize a variable `start = 1`, print out the information as `Showing {{start}} - {{count}} of {{total}}`. Then when I go to the next page `start =  count +1` and `count += count`. However I have no Idea how to do this in a `django template`. I tried with the `with tag` as {%with start = 1%} but it gives me an error `'with' expected at least one variable assignment`

This is where all  the magic happens:

```
{% if table.page %}
        {% with table.page.paginator.count as total %}
            {% with table.page.object_list|length as count %}
                {% with start = 1 %}
                    {% block pagination %}
                        <ul class="pagination">
                            {% block pagination.cardinality %}
                                <li class="cardinality">
                                    {% if total != count %}
                                        {% blocktrans %}
                                            Showing {{ count }} of {{ total }}
                                        {% endblocktrans %}
                                    {% else %}
                                        {{ total }}
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% if total == 1 %}
                                        {{ table.data.verbose_name }}
                                    {% else %}
                                        {{ table.data.verbose_name_plural }}
                                    {% endif %}
                                </li>
                            {% endblock pagination.cardinality %}
                        </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do maths for this. The `page` object already gives you the relevant information: `start_index` and `end_index`.

So:

```
{% with table.page as page %}
Showing {{ page.start_index }} - {{ page.end_index }} of {{ page.paginator.count }}
{% endwith %}
```

Plus, you can use `page.has_other_pages` to determine if there are other pages, rather than your complex logic comparing the total with the current count.

See [the pagination docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/pagination/#page-objects).

Comment: damn thats awesome!. Worked like a charm. and the pagination docs help out it so many more areas.